# Recursive language with non-recursive subsets

Tags: formal-languages, computability, undecidability

I have a professor who is really poor at explaining the material, which is what makes answering his questions very hard. Here is the question:

> Recursive language with non-recursive subsets. Does one exist?

I'm sure it is a very simple and easy answer but I can't figure it out. Don't give me the answer just point me in the right direction and I'm sure I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Take a very big recursive language over any alphabet you like. Verrrry big. Something so big it has all kinds of subsets.

Comment: Looks like I need more than a hint. I think it is possible to have a non-recursive subset, but I can't come up with an example. Can you help out more?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. What's the biggest recursive langauge you can think of?

Comment: In our class we blazed through the topic so fast and in such general terms that I think nobody understood what the professor was talking about. So the only recursive language I can think of is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: I think I got it. I can take any recursive language L. An empty set is part a subset of L. Empty set is non recursive.

Comment: The empty set is recursive: it's accepted by the Turing machine that always says "no". But, as you say, the set of natural numbers is recursive. Can you think of a non-recursive subset of them?